# JavaScript/Ajax: navigator.onLine alternative: serverReachable()

Tags: javascript, ajax

The following code is an alternative to using navigator.onLine - by checking whether the server is reachable.

'Simple' question - how do I make it work?

```
function serverReachable() {
  // IE vs. standard XHR creation
  var x = new ( window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest )( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" ),
      s;
  x.open(
    // requesting the headers is faster, and just enough
    "HEAD",
    // append a random string to the current hostname,
    // to make sure we're not hitting the cache
    "//" + window.location.hostname + "/?rand=" + Math.random(),
    // make a synchronous request
    false
  );
  try {
    x.send();
    s = x.status;
    // Make sure the server is reachable
    return ( s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304 );
  // catch network & other problems
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The above code was taken from the article: http://louisremi.com/2011/04/22/navigator-online-alternative-serverreachable/ but I can't work out why it doesn't work.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I don't see anything. I want it to say "online" or "offline".

Comment: What would you see from console if you `console.log(serverReachable())`?

Comment: It works for me. It returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: @CaseyChu If you use the exact same code as above, you get a text-based output of "true" or "false"??

Comment: @EliUnger The function returns a Boolean value.

Comment: It returns a boolean `true` or `false`. You can make it a string by doing `serverReachable() ? 'online' : 'offline'`.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. But where in the code do I specify what server to check? I mean the whole point of the code is to check whether the server is reachable, right?

Comment: It checks whether the server on which the page is hosted is up. That's `window.location.hostname` in the code. For example, if the code were on StackOverflow, it would try to call the URL `//stackoverflow.com/?rand=12345`. You can replace that with the server you want to check, but watch out for crossdomain restrictions (JavaScript doesn't let you call remote servers without some extra code).

Comment: @CaseyChu thx for your help. For some reason, I only get false, regardless of what server I use. Can you please, give me an example of a server/scenario that would return a true value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "For some reason, I only get false, regardless of what server I use"

You can not pick any random server because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can only do your local domain that you are currently on.